# Ñ in ASCII not recognized

Tags: javascript, ascii

**Code:**

```
$(document).keydown(function(key) {
    switch (parseInt(key.which, 10)) {
        case 65:
            $('img[src*="imgs/A1.png"]').remove();
            break;
        case 83:
            $('img[src*="imgs/S1.png"]').remove();
            break;
        case 68:
            $('img[src*="imgs/D1.png"]').remove();
            break;
        case 70:
            $('img[src*="imgs/F1.png"]').remove();
            break;
        case 74:
            $('img[src*="imgs/J1.png"]').remove();
            break;
        case 75:
            $('img[src*="imgs/K1.png"]').remove();
            break;
        case 165:
            $('img[src*="imgs/Ñ1.png"]').remove();
            break;
        default:
            alert("key not found");
            break;
    }
});
```

I want to remove previously added images if the user presses the correct key. It works alright with "normal" letters, but not with "Ñ". According to the ASCII table, the corresponding number is 165, but it doesn't work (when I press the "Ñ" key, it alerts "key not found").
Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `parseInt` does not return the ASCII/Unicode-value of a character. For example `parseInt("A", 10)` returns `NaN` (not a number) instead of 65. You probably whant to use `key.which.charCodeAt(0)`.

Comment: @vstm I think it actually does. It works for the other letters!

Answer (score 1):

Your script is probably running in a page that was encoded in UTF-8, not ASCII.  And in any case Ñ is not a valid ASCII character.

ASCII is a 7-bit encoding; you're probably thinking of an extended ASCII encoding.

In any case, why don't you replace your "key not found" alert by:

```
alert("key not found: " + parseInt(key.which, 10));
```

Comment: You mean I should change this `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">` ?